# Mongoengine - extend aggregate query with OR

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo, mongoengine

I have an aggregate query via `mongoengine`:

```
Foo.objects.aggregate(*[ { "$match": { "groups.1": { "$exists": True } } }, { "$redact": { "$cond": [ { "$gte": [ { "$size": { "$setIntersection": [ "$groups", my_groups ] } }, 1 ]}, "$$KEEP", "$$PRUNE" ] }} ])
```

But, the results of the query are not enough.
I need to find all documents that match this query `OR` other queries.

How should I do that?
Thank you!

Comment: What is the other query ?

Comment: Foo.objects(users__in = username)

Comment: You can expand your match condition Something like `{ "$match": { $or:[{"groups.1": { "$exists": True } }, {"users":{"$in":[some values]}}] }}`

Comment: Where does the redact takes a place in your example? Can you please provide a full example of combination of my 2 queries?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by combining two queries. You can combine them in both `$redact` stage and in `$match` stage. I did in the match stage as an example. You can move them to redact if that is what you need. Consider adding more details to your post. Add both the queries and expected output.

Comment: Each query (the one in the question and the second in the comment above) returns documents. I need both document,all the documents that match the first query, OR the second one